# Difference between 'Turn away someone' vs 'Turn someone away'

Tags: meaning, phrases

Is `Turn away someone` and `Turn someone away` have the same meaning?

Comment: Yes, the two phrases mean essentially the same.   I would use the first phrase if I were continuing the sentence (e.g., "He turned away the beggar from his door.") and the second if I were not continuing the sentence (e.g., "He turned the beggar away.")  But that's just my personal preference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**turn away** is defined as, [according to Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/turn%20away):

> to refuse admittance or acceptance to
>
> to send away : [reject](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reject), [dismiss](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dismiss)
>
> [repel](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/repel)
>
> [deflect](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/deflect), [avert](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/avert)

As for each individual form of the phrasal verb, they are synonymous with each other with no difference in terms of meaning. The only discrepancy between the two is how frequently used each of them are.

**turn(ing) away someone** does indeed exist, though not commonly used.

Example from [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/turn%20away):

> using tree branches, the campers were able to **turn away** the charging
>   fox, which was apparently rabid

Example from [TheFreeDictionary.com](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/turn+away):

> Extremely high prices in the area have been **turning away** would-be homeowners.

**turn(ing) someone away** is much more widely used, and is what many native speakers prefer.

Example:

> The hiking real estate prices turn people away.

Example, from [Collins Dict.](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/turn-away):

> Turning refugees away would be an inhumane action.